# Getting a RotateDrawable from XML results in crash

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve a RotateDrawable defined in XML but it causes an excetion when I call getDrawable(). Here are my XML and java files:

square.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle" 
    android:id="@+id/mysquare">
    <solid android:color="#0000f8"/>
    <size android:height="200dp" android:width="200dp"></size>
    <padding android:top="0dp"></padding>
</shape>
```

myrotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/square"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%">>
        </rotate>
```

Indicator.java (only relevant code shown)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawablelayout);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAnimate);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    r = getResources();

    /* this is where the exception happens */
    RotateDrawable rt = (RotateDrawable) r.getDrawable(R.drawable.myrotate);


}
```

Can anyone tell me how I'm supposed to get a RotateDrawable from XML?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `>` in line 2 from the bottom of myrotate.xml

```
android:pivotY="50%">>
```

Remove it.